# Creating a hexagonal grid of regular hexagons of definite area anywhere on the globe using shapely

Tags: coordinate-system, shapely, grids-graticules, pyproj

I have a geojson file describing a polygon. I want to create an hexagonal grid on top of this polygon, with regular hexagons of area 90000 square meters.

Right now, I can either guarantee the area, or the regularity, but not both.

Here is my code:

```
def create_hexagon(l, x, y):
    """
    Create a hexagon centered on (x, y)
    :param l: length of the hexagon's edge
    :param x: x-coordinate of the hexagon's center
    :param y: y-coordinate of the hexagon's center
    :return: The polygon containing the hexagon's coordinates
    """
    c = [[x + math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * l, y + math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * l] for angle in range(0, 360, 60)]
    return Polygon(c)

def create_hexgrid(bbox, side):
    """
    returns an array of Points describing hexagons centers that are inside the given bounding_box
    :param bbox: The containing bounding box. The bbox coordinate should be in Webmercator.
    :param side: The size of the hexagons'
    :return: The hexagon grid
    """
    grid = []

    v_step = math.sqrt(3) * side
    h_step = 1.5 * side

    x_min = min(bbox[0], bbox[2])
    x_max = max(bbox[0], bbox[2])
    y_min = min(bbox[1], bbox[3])
    y_max = max(bbox[1], bbox[3])

    h_skip = math.ceil(x_min / h_step) - 1
    h_start = h_skip * h_step

    v_skip = math.ceil(y_min / v_step) - 1
    v_start = v_skip * v_step

    h_end = x_max + h_step
    v_end = y_max + v_step

    if v_start - (v_step / 2.0) < y_min:
        v_start_array = [v_start + (v_step / 2.0), v_start]
    else:
        v_start_array = [v_start - (v_step / 2.0), v_start]

    v_start_idx = int(abs(h_skip) % 2)

    c_x = h_start
    c_y = v_start_array[v_start_idx]
    v_start_idx = (v_start_idx + 1) % 2
    while c_x < h_end:
        while c_y < v_end:
            grid.append((c_x, c_y))
            c_y += v_step
        c_x += h_step
        c_y = v_start_array[v_start_idx]
        v_start_idx = (v_start_idx + 1) % 2

    return grid
```

I can either apply it on my polygon reprojected to webmercator (3857):

```
edge = math.sqrt(RESOLUTION**2/(3/2 * math.sqrt(3)))
hex_centers = create_hexgrid(reprojected.bounds, edge)
hexagons = GeometryCollection([
    shapely.ops.transform(webmercator_to_spherical, create_hexagon(edge, center[0], center[1]))
    for center in hex_centers 
    if any([zone.intersects(
        shapely.ops.transform(webmercator_to_spherical, create_hexagon(edge, center[0], center[1]))
    ) for zone in geometry.geoms])
])
```

and obtain a grid of regular hexagons, but the area would not be `RESOLUTION**2`

[image: grid of regular hexagons]

Or, I can apply it to my polygon reprojected to Albers Equal Area projection :

```
edge = math.sqrt(RESOLUTION**2/(3/2 * math.sqrt(3)))
hex_centers = create_hexgrid(reprojected_true.bounds, edge)
hexagons = GeometryCollection([
    reproject_from_true_meters(create_hexagon(edge, center[0], center[1]))
    for center in hex_centers 
    if any([zone.intersects(
        reproject_from_true_meters(create_hexagon(edge, center[0], center[1]))
    ) for zone in geometry.geoms])
])
```

To endup with a grid of hexagons with the right area, but not regular:[image]

Here is the original polygon geojson:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-64.30624008178711,-36.600369790618835],[-64.30709838867188,-36.60016307220288],[-64.30684089660645,-36.60250584848266],[-64.30615425109862,-36.60243694431346],[-64.30615425109862,-36.61366751126687],[-64.29619789123535,-36.61311635595829],[-64.29645538330078,-36.6160787694227],[-64.29774284362793,-36.61635433698211],[-64.2989444732666,-36.6169054691463],[-64.30117607116699,-36.61814550211169],[-64.30212020874023,-36.61897217967516],[-64.3033218383789,-36.62117660984155],[-64.30435180664062,-36.6229676629369],[-64.30512428283691,-36.62482755864398],[-64.30392265319824,-36.625171978850105],[-64.30632591247559,-36.62765175890191],[-64.28272247314453,-36.64762485464038],[-64.27800178527832,-36.64438818727331],[-64.27396774291992,-36.64108251425615],[-64.27250862121582,-36.637845571969294],[-64.27250862121582,-36.632542202379454],[-64.27216529846191,-36.62572304797872],[-64.26993370056152,-36.620212179400006],[-64.26976203918457,-36.606777786771396],[-64.27070617675781,-36.604297335278915],[-64.27302360534668,-36.60257475259031],[-64.27757263183594,-36.60147227948239],[-64.28186416625977,-36.60085213143531],[-64.28993225097656,-36.59954291363163],[-64.30624008178711,-36.600369790618835]]]}}]}
```

`reprojected` is the projection of this polygon in webmercator
`reprojected_true` is the projection of this polygon in Albers Equal Area projection

Is there just an other projection that I could use?

Comment: Semi-similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749264/covering-earth-with-hexagonal-map-tiles/15825535#15825535

Answer (score 2):

The is no solution to your problem, unfortunately.

On one hand, as soon as you project coordinates on a 2 dimensional map, you need to choose between an equal-area projection (preserving the area) or a conformal projection (preserving local angles), but no projection has both. Of course, some projections make a compromise so that neither are totally preserved in this case, buth distortions are limited. This is the case of the Miller projection, for instance. Using many local projection, if you can tolerate some discontinuities, will minimize the errors because the surface of the Earth is more and more similar to a plane when you zoom in (most can be optimized on your study area by changing the meridian and parallels of reference). EDIT: a practical solution could be to used the UTM projections, which are conformal but with relatively small area distortion. There are 60 zones of 6 degrees, so you will need to manage the discontinuities every 6 degrees. The good thing with UTM is that the distortion will be very little affected by the latitude.

[image]

On the other hand, it is not possible to cover a spherical object with only hexagonal faces (this is why a soccer ball is made of hexagons AND pentagons). If you look at this [demonstration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121175/is-it-possible-to-have-a-spherical-object-with-only-hexagonal-faces), no solid can be composed solely on hexagonal faces (so, even if the Earth is not a true sphere, it cannot be covered by hexagons only.

Comment: I'm aware that my problem isn't solvable if I want my grid to cover the whole surface of the sphere. But as you said, Earth is more and more similar to a plane when you zoom in.

At the scale of a city, there should be okayish solutions. For example, the Albers Equal Area projection renders a pretty okay result over french cities. But an awful one over Argentinian cities. Considering the earth is a sphere, is there a way to "recenter" the Albers Equal Area projection over the center of my polygon for instance?

Comment: @Borbag You are misunderstanding the problem. There are an *infinite* number of Albers Equal Area projections (multiple latitude and longitude variables). There is no one Albers that's applicable everywhere on the globe. And the Earth is a spheroid, not a sphere.

Comment: I wonder how they cut the hexagons and pentagons when they sew footballs and if it is possible to use just hexagons https://www.quora.com/Why-are-footballs-made-with-a-combination-of-hexagons-and-pentagon-shapes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is not really a complete answer but still longer than a comment. First, it seems that it is possible to cover a sphere completely by hexagons. This was proven by Kevin Sahr in 2003 ([PDF HERE](https://www.discreteglobalgrids.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/gdggs03.pdf))- see his website: https://www.discreteglobalgrids.org/ and related publications. There is also a free software running only on Unix and a port to R by Richard Barnes in form of the dggridR package - see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dggridR/vignettes/dggridR.html

However (!) this kind of grid is a nested grid system with predefined resolutions. There are six different grid types, like ISEA3H: *Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area Aperture 3 Hexagonal Grid* with 20 different resolutions, which are all not rounded numbers. For example for resolution 12 the number of hexagons covering the globe are 5,314,412 with each having an area of 95.97785 km². As far as I know, it is not possible with this grid type to have e.g. 100km² but it is a regular grid. You can use your bounding box to cut out the grid from the global grid. Yet, this is not the optimal solution I guess.

EDIT: I just found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38339648/333758) that it requires about 12 pentagons to build the global grid system, but given the millions of resulting hexagons it might be neglible. For mathematicians, of course, it might be not acceptable.

Comment: Interesting thank you. This is the kind of solution I'm looking for. Have a global (nearly all) hexagonal grid, and select the portion of it that suits my needs. Do you know why there isn't one with a resolution I could define? Is there any mathematical reason?

Comment: For implementations also see https://github.com/mocnik-science/geogrid (java native implementation) and https://github.com/correndo/dggridpy (python wrapper for dggridR)